# Bulk insert a semi-structured file (SQL server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to import a file into sql server table, however this is not a normal structured file having a predefined number of columns; the number of columns is not fixed from one file to another and not even from one line to another.

the field terminator is '|' so for example in the first line you will have 3 columns (3 pipe delimiter) and on the next line 10 columns.(10 pipe delimiter)

is it possible to treat these kind of files using the bulk insert function in sql server?

thanks.

Comment: Are the table headers known? also, are the column values in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

bulk Insert into a temp table with single column.
then filter Rows based on number of terminator(|).